# Devops CICD - deploy each project in solution to specific path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, cicd

I have .NET framework solution contains more than 100 projects inside, I have completed build the  whole solution in pipeline build process.
Now I need to deploy each project of them to specific path on my local server using release pipeline.

Anyone help me with resources how to make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make every project under the same solution to deploy to the related location, you should add **IIS web app manage task** and set your specific deploy location to **Physical path**, that is what you need.

[image]

**Note**: you should note that each project corresponds to a **Manage IISWebsite task** and **IIS web app deploy task**, which means that you should add much tasks for your  more than 100 projects. That is the only solution.